# INSTALLING UBUNTU ON DELL INSPIRON WITH XP

Tags: dell, windows-xp, inspiron

Primo noob here.  I would like to install Ubuntu on my laptop.  I have downloaded Universal USB Installer and I am stuck where it asks me to choose (or browse) s Linux distribution and then an IOS.

Can someone be kind and help me  please?

Mike

Comment: It is asking you to choose an **ISO**, not IOS (very different). Did you download an Ubuntu ISO from the [downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) yet? You need one to continue. It will be a large file that may take a while to download.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that you want to dual boot computer with XP and Ubuntu

Best way is to have Ubuntu live cd , or you can create usb drive wit bootable Ubuntu

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Have you checked these page

Comment: I think I may have figured it out and I'm downloading the IOS right now.  I'll have to wait and see.  I do prefer a dual boot but I can't get a CD 'cause I don't have the CD for the laptop.